# How to change the mode of UIDatePicker to millisecond mode in iphone?

Tags: ios4

I want to create an application containing UIDatePicker view . UIDatePicker contains the property of Timer mode ,Date mode,Date and Time mode, Days and Time mode but it don't have property of to convert any of this Mode to MilliSecond Mode .I have stuck here can anybody 
help me .

Answer (score 2):

There is no such  thing...
See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html for a list of modes for UIDatePicker... 
They are the following:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDatePickerModeTime,
   UIDatePickerModeDate,
   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
} UIDatePickerMode;
```